# SSRS Fit to Proportion Image

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-dynamics

I have an image in an SSRS report, and it doesn't seem to be doing "FitProportional" (by which I assume means it will grow or shrink proportionally, depending on the cell size).

**FitProportional** keeps it small, proportional to the cell size.
**Clip** clips it to the cell size of the upper left corner of the photo.
**Fit** stretches the photo out of proportion
**AutoSize** skews the whole report to the size of a large photograph.

is there an additional setting I can apply to have the photo actually increase or shrink proportional to the cell size?  Or should I make sure the photos are already sized properly, before being used by the SSRS report.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but too much to fit in a comment.

I'm not sure what other option you could want other centering, these cover everything else.

**AutoSize** : Resizes the **cell** to the size of the image's original size

**Fit** : stretches and scales the image to fit the cell perfectly, image ratio is no maintained and the image fills the cell.

**FitProportial** : keeps the image width vs height ratio the same but set the image size to be as wide or tall as possible to fill the cell either vertically or horizontally.

**Clip** : Anchors the image in the top left corner of the cell. The image is not resized but only the portion of the image that fits within the cell is visible.

If you still think there is something missing, maybe post some screen shots with examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alan.  I need fit proportional to always increase the size horizontally, keeping the integrity of the proportions - even if it means the bottom or top has been cut off, which is what I'm used to the term meaning with my design tools. 
 What's happening is it increase as much as possible, width and height, and then stops at the borders.  Maybe I'm looking for a fill proportional option.

Comment: I'm getting around this for now by creating powerpoint templates that are perfectly sized, and asking my users to resize their graphics in advance, and then setting the picture to "fill" - assuming no excessive skewing will occur.

Comment: Ah I see, so what you need is a "FitProportialToWidth" option.